# Problem using mutiple image2d across diferent shaders

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, compute-shader

Im new to opengl and im having problems using multiple image2d objects across two compute shaders invocations.

I create the textures like this:

```
GLuint light_texture[3];
glGenTextures(3, light_texture);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1 + i);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, light_texture[i]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32UI, TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);        
    glBindImageTexture(i+1, light_texture[i], 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_READ_WRITE, GL_R32UI);    
}
computeShader.use();
computeShader.setInt("img_red",1);
computeShader.setInt("img_green", 2);
computeShader.setInt("img_blue", 3);
mixShader.use();
mixShader.setInt("img_red", 1);
mixShader.setInt("img_green", 2);
mixShader.setInt("img_blue", 3);
```

and run the shaders:

```
computeShader.use();
glDispatchCompute((GLuint)TEXTURE_WIDTH, (GLuint)TEXTURE_HEIGHT, 1);
glMemoryBarrier(GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS);
  
mixShader.use();
glDispatchCompute((GLuint)TEXTURE_WIDTH, (GLuint)TEXTURE_HEIGHT, 1);
```

The first shader just sets some values for each of the images

computeShader:

```
layout (local_size_x = 1, local_size_y = 1) in;


layout (binding = 1,r32ui) uniform coherent uimage2D img_red;
layout (binding = 2,r32ui) uniform coherent uimage2D img_green;
layout (binding = 3,r32ui) uniform coherent uimage2D img_blue;


void main()
{
    ivec2 pixel_position = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);
    imageStore(img_red, pixel_position, uvec4(600));
    imageStore(img_green, pixel_position, uvec4(1));
    imageStore(img_blue, pixel_position, ivec4(1));


    
}
```

And to test if it works i just made the mix shader render white if it reads something greater than 0 and to draw red if it doesent.

mixShader:

```
#version 460 core

layout (local_size_x = 1, local_size_y = 1) in;
layout (binding = 0,rgba32f) uniform image2D target_texture;
layout (binding = 1,r32ui) uniform coherent uimage2D img_red;
layout (binding = 2,r32ui) uniform coherent uimage2D img_green;
layout (binding = 3,r32ui) uniform coherent uimage2D img_blue;



void main(){
    ivec2 pixel_position = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);
    vec4 color;
    if(imageLoad(img_red, pixel_position).r>0 ||imageLoad(img_green, pixel_position).r>0||imageLoad(img_blue, pixel_position).r>0){
        color =vec4(1,1,1,1);
    }else{
        color = vec4(1,0,0,1);
    }
    

    imageStore(target_texture, pixel_position, color);


}
```

I keep getting red.
I dont khow if the problem is in the texture creation or in the shaders but i cant get it to work.

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference, but have you tried using `GL_RED_INTEGER` instead of `GL_RED`?

Comment: Presumably setInt is a wrapper for glUniform1i and use is a wrapper for glUseProgram?

Comment: @BDL Nope, i just tried it. I think that argument is for data loading, and i dont load any data into the image. The data is generated on the shader.

Comment: @user253751 Yes they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by changing the way the textures are created:

```
GLuint color_textures[3];
glGenTextures(3,color_textures);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, color_textures[i]);
    glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_R32UI,TEXTURE_WIDTH,TEXTURE_HEIGHT);
    glBindImageTexture(i+1, color_textures[i], 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_READ_WRITE, GL_R32UI);

}
```